# Excel If value in Cell is 181 then I want to display value in F28

Tags: excel, if-statement

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work

```
=IF(D28="181", "",F28)
```

I'm making a filter to display a value in a column of cells the the associated row value is 181, basically I have a bunch of data and column D identifies the type of data. So I want to know if D(#)=181 if it does display the column value from F#

but it doesn't seem to mater what value I have in D it always outputs something in the cell when it should be empty.

Comment: In addition to having your `result if True`  and `result if False` reversed, as pointed out below, `181` and `"181"` are two different values.  One is a string, the other is a number.  So be certain the data type in D# is the same as what you have in your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value if true and value if false statements are switched. Try
 `=IF(D28 = 181, F28, "")`

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need the quotes around 181.